# 52 votes in favor/for

Tags: prepositions, intransitive-preposition

Normally, prepositions require objects. However, someone told me the following is correct:

> 1. The House of Representatives approved the budget, with 52 votes **for**, 16 against and 12 abstentions.

I'd like to know when such object-less prepositions are possible. Is the following correct?

> 2. The House of Representatives approved the budget, with 52 votes **for**.

Compare the following, with "in favor" in place of "for":

> 3. The House of Representatives approved the budget, with 52 votes **in favor**.

Are #2 and #3 equally acceptable?

Comment: 2. Is an ellipsis: "with 52 votes for [the motion/proposal/budget]."

Comment: No. 2 is definitely a little awkward, and less common than No.3

Comment: What about the "for" in No. 1?